# dongle alternative for cloud software

Tags: cloud, copy-protection

Our software is currently USB dongle-protected.  If we want to run it in a cloud environment, obviously that's no longer an option.

The cloud itself would be under control of our customer - they have already set up such an environment.

Are there any good protection schemes for such an environment?

Comment: If you're running it in a cloud environment (presumably as some form of software as a service), won't you control the servers/software install yourselves? (I presume I'm missing something here, so you might want to clarify your question.) Do you mean you'll be letting your customers install it on their own cloud environments? (If so, a periodic check-in with a licensing server may be a sensible solution.)

Comment: I meant letting user install on their own cloud - I just edited the question with that extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to [limit the number of concurrent users of your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065026/count-and-limit-the-number-of-users-on-my-app) or maybe [limit the number of logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406905/secure-an-asp-net-application-using-limit-for-number-of-logins).

Comment: The limits you mentioned can easily be bypassed as the customer can simply deploy to different instances of cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the [DinkeyWeb](http://www.microcosm.co.uk/websiteprotection.php) system.
You can secure your app whether it's deployed on your own server or your customers server.